# How can I use java.util.properties in jruby?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I'm working with a class provided on this site:https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/jruby-oracle11g-330825.html

I'm setting up SSL and I need to pass a list of java.util.properties to Driver manager.

I figure I do something like this...

```
# jdbc_connection.rb

require 'java'

java_import 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
java_import 'java.sql.DriverManager'
java_import 'java.util.Properties' #<---Import here

class OracleConnection

  @conn = nil

  def initialize (url)
    @url = url
    #I want to create the array of properties here and populate it with my SSL properties. I'm really lost here.

    # Load driver class
    oradriver = OracleDriver.new

    DriverManager.registerDriver oradriver
    #I want to pass the Properties to DriverManager.
    @conn = DriverManager.get_connection url, properties 
    @conn.auto_commit = false

  end
```

I'm hung up on how to create the properties in ruby and pass them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

treat the `java.util.Properties` Java class like a Ruby one (all of its [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) methods are available)

also if you look at the docs `Properties extends Hashtable` and [Hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is a (implements) `Map`.

JRuby provides extension for all map types to act very much like a Ruby `Hash`.

```rb
properties = java.util.Properties.new
properties.put 'a.ssl.key', 'A-VALUE' # Java style (put inherited from Hashtable)
properties['another.ssl.key'] = 'ANOTHER' # Ruby Hash style
```